# Formula to Generate List of Specific Numbers

Tags: python, list, loops, sequence, fibonacci

I am relatively new to programing and I'm trying to generate a list of numbers using this formula.

If "i" is the index of the list, the formula would be list[i] = list[i-2] + list[i-3]. The first few numbers would look like this if you started with 1,1,1.

1,1,1,2,2,3,4,5,7,9,12,16,21,28,37,49,65,86.etc. To get each number(after the 1,1,1) you skip back one number, then take the sums of the previous two numbers e.g. 49 was from the sum of 21 and 28.

The process of finding the numbers is similar to Fibonacci but these numbers are worlds different.

My code looks like this:

```
start = [1,1,1] #the list must start with three 1's
list1 = start #list1 starts with 'start'
newList = []
ammountOfNumbers = int(raw_input("Enter the ammount of numbers to be generated(n >= 3): "))# to dictate length of generated list


def generateList(newList, aList, ammountOfNumbers, *a):
    while len(aList) <= ammountOfNumbers: #while length of list is less than or = size of list you want generated
        for x in range((ammountOfNumbers-1)):
            newList.append(x) #this puts value of x in index '0' 
            newList[x] = aList[len(aList)-1] + aList[len(aList)-2] # generate next number
            aList += newList #add the next generated number to the list
            x+=1
        print
        #print "Inside: ", aList #test
        #print "Length inside: ",len(aList) #test
        print
        return aList


final = generateList(newList, list1, ammountOfNumbers) # equal to the value of list1
print"Final List: " , final
print
print"Length Outside: ", len(final) #wrong value
```

It obviously doesn't work correctly right now. I'm hoping to be able to generate a list of around 500 of these numbers. Does anyone have any suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: Lots of problems here, but for starters move your return statement outside the while loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a generator:

```
from collections import deque
def generate_list():
    que = deque([1,1,1],3)
    yield 1
    yield 1
    yield 1
    while True:
        out = que[-3]+que[-2]
        yield out
        que.append(out)
```

This will generate an *infinite* series of according to that recurrence relation.  To truncate it, I would use `itertools.islice`.  Alternatively, you could pass in a number to be the maximal number that you want and only loop the appropriate number of times.

---

To create a general recurrence relation function I'd do something like:

```
def recurrence_relation(seed,func):
    seed = list(seed)
    que = deque(seed,len(seed))
    for x in seed:
        yield seed
    while True:
        out = func(que)
        yield out
        queue.append(out)
```

To use this for your problem, it would look like:

```
series = recurrence_relation([1,1,1],lambda x:x[-3] + x[-2])
for item in islice(series,0,500):
    #do something
```

I think this combines the nice "seeding" ability proposed by Blender with a very generally scalable formalism that using a `deque` allows as I originally proposed.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a generator:

```
def sequence(start):
    a, b, c = start

    yield a
    yield b

    while True:
        yield c
        a, b, c = b, c, a + b
```

Since the generator will keep going forever, you will have to stop it somehow:

```
for i, n in enumerate(sequence([1, 1, 1])):
    if i > 100:
        break

    print n
```

Or with `itertools`:

```
from itertools import islice:

for n in islice(sequence([1, 1, 1]), 100):
    print n
```

Comment: +1 -- I like this.  Clever use of unpacking.  It doesn't scale very nicely when the recurrence relation has more items in it ... but most recurrence relations that I've seen only require a few terms.

Comment: @mgilson: Yep, your deque solution is more more versatile. I would put the seed in an argument and just `yield` from it, as that way you can define the recurrence relation in an anonymous function.

Comment: Yeah, I just thought about that.

Comment: A generator doesn't store the information in memory though right? So say I wanted to then print lists of all the perfect squares/cubes or all of the even numbers. Is that still possible?

Comment: @AndrewRyanKaplan: Sure, you can turn the generator into a list by doing `list(islice(sequence([1, 1, 1]), 100))`.

Comment: @Blender:I also want to use list comprehensions. So your saying the most efficient way to do this would be: Use a generator to create numbers, turn the generator into a list, and then use list comprehensions?

Comment: @AndrewRyanKaplan: A list comprehension is an inline `for` loop in brackets. A generator expression is the same, but instead of brackets, it has parentheses and doesn't return anything until you request it. A generator is just a function that `yield`s values, so you can't turn this into a generator expression.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
def solve(n):
    lis=[1,1,1]
    if n<=3:
        return lis[:n]
    while len(lis)!=n:
        lis.append(lis[-2]+lis[-3])
    return lis

print solve(20)
```

**output:**

```
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9, 12, 16, 21, 28, 37, 49, 65, 86, 114, 151]
```

Comment: FWIW, this will keep a list of size `n` in memory.  (It will also build the entire list before you can start using it).

Comment: @Ashwini Chaudhary: Thanks, this is great. I'm going to try to do it this way, and using a generator.